# AuthenticationHandler calls everytime even Controller is not required Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have added Custom security it is working fine for authrization. I don't know why `Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()` is calling for controller that don't needs authorization.

In Startup.cs below is code how I Initilize  it .

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAutoMapper();

c.AddSecurityDefinition(MM.AuthenticationScheme, new ApiKeyScheme()
            {
                Description = "API Key Authorization header using the mm Api Key scheme. Example: \"MM-API-KEY: {MM-API-KEY}\"",
                Name = "MM-API-KEY",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });
auth.AddPolicy(MM.AuthenticationScheme, b =>
            {
                b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                b.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string> { MenulogApiKey.AuthenticationScheme };
            });

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // the scheme name has to match the value we're going to use in                 options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = MM.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MM.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddMenulogApiKeyAuth(o => { });


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
         app.UseAuthentication();
         }
```

In KeyHandler Class I am using like this :

```
internal class MMApiKeyHandler : AuthenticationHandler<MMApiKeyAuthOptions>
```

Comment: This is just the way authentication works. You will see `UseAuthentication` in your middleware pipeline configuration which means you'll always be authenticating your users - authorisation simply uses the authenticated user to determine whether or not access is allowed.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks   for your help , Yes it was because of  `UseAuthentication `

Answer (score -1):

(Blind guess)

The authentication filter may be set up as a global filter.

Search for something like `filters.Add(`

or examine the code where `GlobalFilters.Filters` are used.